# Adjusting Historical Stock Prices for Splits Using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database consisting of a table with unadjusted security prices and another table of stock splits. I'm wondering if there's a SQL function or trigger I can write to view adjusted historical prices.

For Example: Apple had a 4-for-1 stock split on 8/31/20. Therefore, I need to **adjust all prices before 8/31/2020 by 0.25.**

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| Ticker | Split Date | Adjustment |
+--------+------------+------------+
| AAPL   | 2020-08-31 |       0.25 |
+--------+------------+------------+

+--------+------------+---------+
| Ticker |    Date    | Unadj   |
+--------+------------+---------+
| AAPL   | 2020-09-01 | 134.18  |
| AAPL   | 2020-08-31 | 129.04  |
| AAPL   | 2020-08-28 | 499.23* |
| AAPL   | 2020-08-27 | 500.04* |
| AAPL   | 2020-08-26 | 506.09* |
+--------+------------+---------+
```

* These values and all previous values should be multiplied by 0.25

Should I be using a window function or is there something else I should be looking at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can use a window function.

The `exp()`, `ln()`, and `sum()` combination work to multiply all the splits if there are more than one.

```
 select p.*, 
       coalesce(
         exp(
           sum(ln(s.adjustment)) 
             over (partition by p.ticker
                       order by p.ddate desc
                rows between unbounded preceding
                         and 1 preceding)
         ), 1
       ) * p.unadj as adjusted
  from prices p
       left join splits s 
              on s.ticker = p.ticker 
             and s.split_date = p.ddate;

 ticker |   ddate    | unadj  |        adjusted        
--------+------------+--------+------------------------
 AAPL   | 2020-09-01 | 134.18 |                 134.18
 AAPL   | 2020-08-31 | 129.04 |                 129.04
 AAPL   | 2020-08-28 | 499.23 | 124.807500000000000000
 AAPL   | 2020-08-27 | 500.04 | 125.010000000000000000
 AAPL   | 2020-08-26 | 506.09 | 126.522500000000000000
(5 rows)
```